# velocity foreach loop - iterated array gets updated without being used in an assignment

Tags: arrays, foreach, velocity

I faced a very strange behaviour in the foreach loop of the following velocity template:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>

#set( $arrayOfArray = [[1]] )
#set( $new_arrOfArray = [] )
#set( $new_arr = [] )
                        <tr><td>Line 9</td><td>arrayOfArray: $arrayOfArray</td></tr>
#foreach ($arr in $arrayOfArray)
                        <tr><td>Line 11</td><td>arrayOfArray: $arrayOfArray</td></tr>
    #set( $new_arr = $arr )
                        <tr><td>Line 13</td><td>arrayOfArray: $arrayOfArray</td></tr>
    #if ($new_arr.add([ true ])) #end
                        <tr><td>Line 15</td><td>arrayOfArray: $arrayOfArray</td></tr>
    #if ($new_arr.add([5,6])) #end
                        <tr><td>Line 17</td><td>arrayOfArray: $arrayOfArray</td></tr>
    #if ($new_arrOfArray.add($new_arr)) #end
                        <tr><td>Line 19</td><td>arrayOfArray: $arrayOfArray</td></tr>
#end
                        <tr><td>Line 21</td><td>arrayOfArray: $arrayOfArray</td></tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I'm looping through an array of array (for the sake of simplicity I just put a single array into $arrayOfArray in this example, but real life is of course more complex).
As you can also see from the code I do not manipulate the variable $arrayOfArray at all. However, the code generates the following output:

Line 9 arrayOfArray: [[1]]
Line 11 arrayOfArray: [[1]]
Line 13 arrayOfArray: [[1]]
Line 15 arrayOfArray: [[1, [true]]]
Line 17 arrayOfArray: [[1, [true], [5, 6]]]
Line 19 arrayOfArray: [[1, [true], [5, 6]]]
Line 21 arrayOfArray: [[1, [true], [5, 6]]]

So, it seems whenever I add a new array element to $new_arr the variable $arrayOfArray gets also updated.
Is anyone able to explain this behaviour??
Any help highly appreciated.

Andreas

Comment: I reverted back the edits done on my post. I shifted the printouts "<tr><td>Line..." more to the right by intention as these lines are for debugging purposes only. Shifting them more to the right improves readability of the "real code".

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit uncertain what you need to do. Would cloning help ? Replacing

```
#set( $new_arr = $arr )
```

by

```
#set( $new_arr = $arr.clone() )
```

will keep your $arrayOfArray untouched, while the $new_arrOfArray will be [[1, [true], [5, 6]]] at the end.

But maybe I'm missing some point here ...

Comment: I tested this already. Unfortunately it does not help at all... :-(
I guess the only way to solve this is not using arrays of arrays. Instead I will try putting the array to be processed into a string with some kind of delimiter. Not very nice...

Comment: That is strange. I actually tested the clone and it works for me, in the sense that the arrayOfArray remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

By `#set( $new_arr = $arr )` you are setting `$new_arr` to be a *reference* to `$arr`.

`$arr`, in turn, is a *reference* to `$arrayOfArray` at a certain index.

When calling `new_arr.add()`, you're thereby calling `$arrayOfArray[$someIndex].add()` by reference.

Comment: Hmmm... that was my fear, too.
But is there a way preventing this behaviour?

Comment: @Andreas I honestly have no idea, since I'm super unfamiliar with Velocity. There is some discussion [under this link](http://forum.percussion.com/showthread.php?658-Passing-variables-into-Velocity-macros-by-value), although it doesn't look particularily helpful for your case. See also [this discussion on the project's JIRA where they seem to have promised pass-by-value behavior for 2.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VELOCITY-687)